# Understanding 場合、断っています

Tags: grammar

Regarding the foreigners that Trump doesn't like:

> このため日本航空と全日空は、先月３０日から、この国の人たちがアメリカに行く飛行機に乗る予定だとわかった場合、断っています。
>   Because of this, from the 30th of last month 日本航空 and 全日空 are refusing cases in which it is clear that people from these countries are planning on getting on a plane going to America.

I think I might be mistranslating this. 
I'm unclear on what is being refused with 断る. Why is there a comma where I'd expect to see を? And what exactly does "rejecting cases in which ..." mean? Are they stopping them at the point of boarding the plane or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「このため日本航空{にほんこうくう}と全日空{ぜんにっくう}は、先月{せんげつ}３０日{にち}から、この国{くに}の人{ひと}たちがアメリカに行{い}く飛行機{ひこうき}に乗{の}る予定{よてい}だとわかった場合{ばあい}、断{ことわ}っています。」

As far as grammar, the object of the verb phrase 「断っている」 ("to have been denying") is **not** 「場合」 ("the cases").  It is the "**implied**" 「この国の人たちの搭乗{とうじょう}」 ("the boarding of この国の人たち").  In Japanese, the object of a verb does not have to be explicitly mentioned.

Your translation is good; It is just not a literal one.

Why the comma?  It is mostly because there are so many words used between the subject (日本航空と全日空) and the verb (断っています).  The comma helps the reader keep track of the sentence structure.

It does not say 「場合を」 because, as I stated above, 「場合」 is not the object of the verb 「断る」.  (「場合を断る」 is not said in any kind of situation in the first place.) 「～～場合」 here simply means "in cases where ~~".

From this sentence alone, we could not tell where or how the two airlines are stopping the passengers.  I am just imagining it would be when reservations are made and/or at the airport counter.